# Haskell Vector performance compared to Scala

Tags: performance, scala, haskell

I have a very simple piece of code in Haskell and Scala. This code is intended to run in a very tight loop so performance matters. The problem is that Haskell is about 10x slower than Scala. Here it is Haskell code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU

newtype AffineTransform = AffineTransform {get :: (VU.Vector Double)} deriving (Show)

{-# INLINE runAffineTransform #-}
runAffineTransform :: AffineTransform -> (Double, Double) -> (Double, Double)
runAffineTransform affTr (!x, !y) = (get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 0 * x + get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 1 * y + get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 2, 
                                      get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 3 * x + get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 4 * y + get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 5)

testAffineTransformSpeed :: AffineTransform -> Int -> (Double, Double)
testAffineTransformSpeed affTr count = go count (0.5, 0.5)
  where go :: Int -> (Double, Double) -> (Double, Double)
        go 0 res = res
        go !n !res = go (n-1) (runAffineTransform affTr res)
```

What more can be done to improve this code?

Comment: How did you compile it, and with which compiler?

Comment: It was compiled with ghc 7.6.3. The options are "-O2 -Wall -funbox-strict-fields -threaded -rtsopts". I expected -funbox-strict-fields is sufficient, but it was not the case. Well, i'm a complete newbie, so my expectations may be a little off.

Comment: Why do you need `Vector`s to represent affine transform? It seems more reasonable to make an ADT for it, and process arrays of coordinates.

Comment: Because I need many different random affine transforms (for generation of flame fractals) and in my opinion initialization logic for vectors is more clear. In this case I can generate random vector and transform it using Vector operations. Working with separate coordinates seems harder. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You can make affine transform ADT an instance of `fixed-vector` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector) and get all the power of vector operations as well. What do you mean by "separate coordinates"? Finally, is there more coordinates or transforms in your application?

Comment: I meant writing affine transform using something like (a*x+b*y+c,d*x+e*y+f). Probably you are right about fixed-vector package, but keep in mind it is the first program I'm writing in Haskell and probably I have many baggage from imperative world, so simple vectors seemed natural.

Comment: Your code is much more awkward. Using array for fixed sized structure is not natural in any language, from `C` to `Haskell`.

Comment: BTW use @relies (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to answer in comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem is that

```
runAffineTransform affTr (!x, !y) = (get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 0 * x
                                     + get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 1 * y
                                     + get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 2, 
                                       get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 3 * x
                                     + get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 4 * y
                                     + get affTr `VU.unsafeIndex` 5)
```

produces a pair of *thunks*. The components are not evaluated when `runAffineTransform` is called, they remain thunks until some consumer demands them to be evaluated.

```
testAffineTransformSpeed affTr count = go count (0.5, 0.5)
  where go :: Int -> (Double, Double) -> (Double, Double)
        go 0 res = res
        go !n !res = go (n-1) (runAffineTransform affTr res)
```

is not that consumer, the bang on `res` only evaluates it to the outermost constructor, `(,)`, and you get a result of

```
runAffineTransform affTr (runAffineTrasform affTr (runAffineTransform affTr (...)))
```

which is evaluated only at the end, when finally the normal form is demanded.

If you force the components of the result to be evaluated immediately,

```
runAffineTransform affTr (!x, !y) = case
  (  get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 0 * x
   + get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 1 * y
   + get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 2
  ,  get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 3 * x
   + get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 4 * y
   + get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 5
  ) of (!a,!b) -> (a,b)
```

and let it be inlined, the main difference to [jtobin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193741/jtobin)'s version using a custom strict pair of unboxed `Double#`s is that for the loop in `testAffineTransformSpeed` you get one initial iteration using the boxed `Double`s as argument, and at the end, the components of the result are boxed, which adds a bit of constant overhead (something around 5 nanoseconds per loop on my box). The main part of the loop takes an `Int#` and two `Double#` arguments in both cases and the loop body is identical except for the boxing when `n = 0` is reached.

Of course, forcing the immediate evaluation of the components by using an unboxed strict pair type is nicer.

Comment: When is `!(!x,!y)` ever useful?

Comment: In a `let` or `where` binding. But here it's just a remnant of deleting one character too few from `!res@(!x,!y)`. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 9):

I defined the following strict/unboxed pair type:

```
import System.Random.MWC -- for later
import Control.DeepSeq

data SP = SP {
    one :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double
  , two :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double
  } deriving Show

instance NFData SP where
  rnf p = rnf (one p) `seq` rnf (two p) `seq` ()
```

and replaced it in the `runAffineTransform` function:

```
runAffineTransform2 :: AffineTransform -> SP -> SP
runAffineTransform2 affTr !(SP x y) =
  SP (  get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 0 * x
      + get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 1 * y
      + get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 2     )

     (  get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 3 * x
      + get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 4 * y
      + get affTr `U.unsafeIndex` 5     )
{-# INLINE runAffineTransform2 #-}
```

then ran this benchmark suite:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  g  <- create
  zs <- fmap (AffineTransform . U.fromList)
             (replicateM 100000 (uniformR (0 :: Double, 1) g))

  let myConfig = defaultConfig { cfgPerformGC = ljust True }

  defaultMainWith myConfig (return ()) [
      bench "yours" $ nf (testAffineTransformSpeed  zs) 10
    , bench "mine"  $ nf (testAffineTransformSpeed2 zs) 10
    ]
```

Compiled with `-O2` and ran, and observed some (~4x) speedup:

```
benchmarking yours
mean: 257.4559 ns, lb 256.2492 ns, ub 258.9761 ns, ci 0.950
std dev: 6.889905 ns, lb 5.688330 ns, ub 8.839753 ns, ci 0.950
found 5 outliers among 100 samples (5.0%)
  3 (3.0%) high mild
  2 (2.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 20.944%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers

benchmarking mine
mean: 69.56408 ns, lb 69.29910 ns, ub 69.86838 ns, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.448874 ns, lb 1.261444 ns, ub 1.718074 ns, ci 0.950
found 4 outliers among 100 samples (4.0%)
  4 (4.0%) high mild
variance introduced by outliers: 14.190%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

Full code is in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jtobin/6303260).

**EDIT**

I also posted criterion's output report [here](http://jtobin.ca/so_bench.html).

Comment: Nice, now on my computer it very slightly outperforms Scala (Java). And what is the lesson to be learned? Strictness annotations are not enough (they do not unbox automatically?)? Sometimes you must manually create unboxed (unpacked) data structure?

Comment: @user2705843 Slides (4) and (9) are relevant here: http://johantibell.com/files/haskell-performance-patterns.html

Comment: That `NFData` instance for `SP` is totally wasting work. And quite a lot of it, in fact. It implicitly creates `Double` constructors to point to the unpacked values in the `SP`, forces them, and then throws them away. `rnf a = seq a ()` would be far more efficient and correct.

Comment: @Carl Thanks.  Making that change doesn't make any (time) difference here, though.

Comment: (nor memory, it seems)

Comment: Using ghc's `-fllvm` option should give you a small further speedup - about 10% on my system.

Comment: On my system -fllvm gives exactly nothing. One more question, when the program is run with "+RTS -N4" it is much slower (20-30%) then "+RTS -N1". Currently I do not use any parallelization. Is this normal?

Comment: Edit. My previous comment was WRONG. -llvm adds a lot. Running the function 1e9 times gives reduction in execution time from 5.353 s to 3.861 s.

Comment: `(replicateM 100000 (uniformR (0 :: Double, 1) g))` -- seems to make no sense while only 6 first elements are used.

Comment: If you don't use threads, turning on the parallel runtime can lead to performance loss, yes. Avoid -threaded unless you are actually writing parallel code.

Comment: @Carl You're underestimating GHC, `case p_aIf of _ { AffTran.SP _ _ -> GHC.Tuple.() }` is what it produces for the `NFData` instance. It knows the components are unboxed and sees no reason to evaluate them once again.

Comment: @Carl `seq` is simply an annotation saying that "This needs to be strictly evaluated by this point in time".  `ghc` is free to not re-evaluate it if it knows that the value is already in weak-head normal form.

Comment: Guess GHC is smarter about that than I was giving it credit for.